# Temp Variables in Oracle SQL Loader

Tags: oracle

I need to upload data from flat files.

**Platform/Version:** `Oracle 10g/Windows`

My Flat file looks like below:

```
H,1,10302014
P,10.00,ABC
P,15.00,XYZ
P,14.75,BBY
T,3
```

- First Record - Header (Row Indicator, FileType, Date)
- second to Fourth - Detal Records (Row Indicator, Amount, Name)
- Last Record - Trailer (Row Indicator, Number of Detail Records)

> ```
> create table Mytable
> (Row_ind Varchar2(2),
> Amount number(6,2),
> name varchar2(15),
> file_Dt date);
> ```

I need to use the date(10302014) from header record to while inserting the detail records.  Is is possible?

**Note:**

> The file size is over a million records and i don't have update
>   permission on the file (the file is NOT in ASCII format)

Comment: Is it appropriate to use an EXTERNAL table? You may use it + select to fill MyTable, but I can't say anything about the performance

Comment: Well, the client has the control file in place.  So..

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Oracle 9i or above, there's a way to bind a value and use it later in the process, but I'm assuming you can tell the customer how to write or modify the control file.
I'm wondering if that might work where you use multiple inserts (the header record to a table maybe just to bind the column to a date column) and on the succeeding inserts include the bound column. Search Oracle for that on sql*loader. I found part of it [here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ#Can_one_modify_data_as_the_database_gets_loaded.3F).